# Creating same hashes like symfony2 does with java (SHA-512)

Tags: java, php, symfony, hash, sha

I have an old Symfony2 based application here and I am developing a replacement with Dropwizard in Java.
I migrated all User records from old DB into my new Datamodel.
I also added new fields for passwords and imported the old password and salt fields, too.

Now I want to make the well known procedure. Let the user login, try against new password field. If it fails try the migrated ones, if they work, encode the cleartext password with the new algorithm and store the new hash in the new pasword field. So that the users are porting there password hashes from old procedure to the new one.

Sounds simple and normaly it's work as usual, but this Symfony and PHP drives me crazy.

Where I stuck is to create the same hash with java as symfony does.
The old application uses the MessageDigestPasswordEncoder with "sha512", base64 encoding and 5000 iterations, all defaults ;)

The important methods are:

MessageDigestPasswordEncoder:

```
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt) {
  if ($this->isPasswordTooLong($raw)) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid password.');
  }

  if (!in_array($this->algorithm, hash_algos(), true)) {
    throw new \LogicException(sprintf('The algorithm "%s" is not supported.', $this->algorithm));
  }

  $salted = $this->mergePasswordAndSalt($raw, $salt);
  $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $salted, true);

  // "stretch" hash
  for ($i = 1; $i < $this->iterations; ++$i) {
    $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $digest.$salted, true);
  }

  return $this->encodeHashAsBase64 ? base64_encode($digest) : bin2hex($digest);
}
```

And BasePasswordEncoder:

```
protected function mergePasswordAndSalt($password, $salt) {
  if (empty($salt)) {
    return $password;
  }

  if (false !== strrpos($salt, '{') || false !== strrpos($salt, '}')) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cannot use { or } in salt.');
  }

  return $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
}
```

It's seems straight forward but I stuck with it.
As I read this it does:

1. Merge salt and clear text password to: "password{salt}"
2. Hash this string with SHA-512 and return a binary string into digest variable
3. iterate 5k times and use digest concatenated with merged cleartext password to rehash into digest
4. encode digest to base64

So here are my try in Java:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public void legacyEncryption(String salt, String clearPassword) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
  // Get digester instance for algorithm "SHA-512" using BounceCastle
  MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512", new BouncyCastleProvider());

  // Create salted password string
  String mergedPasswordAndSalt = clearPassword + "{" + salt + "}";

  // First time hash the input string by using UTF-8 encoded bytes.
  byte[] hash = digester.digest(mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8"));

  // Loop 5k times
  for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    // Concatenate the hash bytes with the clearPassword bytes and rehash
    hash = digester.digest(ArrayUtils.addAll(hash, mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
  }

  // Log the resulting hash as base64 String
  logger.info("Legace password digest: salt=" + salt + " hash=" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash));
}
```

Does anybody see the problem? I think the difference is in the result of the:
PHP: binary.binary
and the
JAVA: addAll(byte[],byte[])

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you used BouncyCastleProvider please

Comment: Because the time i've written this bounce castle was the defacto standard for everyone who wanted a security provider with good defaults. Nova days I would use openssl impl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation on php side is correctly doing 5k iterations by doing first round of hashing and then looping 4999 times.

```
$digest = hash($this->algorithm, $salted, true);

for ($i = 1; $i < $this->iterations; ++$i) {
  $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $digest.$salted, true);
}
```

In the the java implementation the for loop starts at 0 which results in 5k + 1 iteration.

By starting the for loop at 1 in java too, the resulting password hashes are then equals.

```
byte[] hash = digester.digest(mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8"));

for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  hash = digester.digest(ArrayUtils.addAll(hash, mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}
```

Comment: Sounds good and makes allot of sense ;) I will give it try tomorrow. Just now finished writing today

Comment: In the PHP code, if `$this->iterations` is `5,000` and `$i` is initialized to `1` in the for loop, then the for loop would iterate `4,999` times, not `5,000` times. And since you say the first round is done outside of the loop in the PHP code, then both the PHP and Java code should iterate `5,000` times.

Comment: You are correct, the PHP code does iterate 5000 (4999 + 1) times. However, the Java code does iterate 5001 times (5000 + 1), since it also has the initial round outside of the loop. I confused both languages in my answer, sorry. I'll fix that. I still think it is the root of the problem, though.

Comment: Not realy the best answer ;) but it was the point. I over read all the time that in the php code the loop start at 1 and not at 0, because we want 5k loops and not +1 ;) I changed my code regarding the php code to start at 1 and now my result hash is correct. I could encode my testpassword. THX alot

Comment: I send in an editing of your post to a correct answer. I overhault the complete text. Hope it's ok for you. It's still in review and possible not accepted.

Comment: Seems like your edit got rejected and I can't see how (if) I can still accept it - anyway, I adjusted the answers based on the changes in your edit. ;)